# calculate and display file MD5 Hash in a label

Tags: c#, md5

How can the MD5 Hash of a file be calculated and displayed in a label?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

```
label1.Text = GetMD5HashFromFile("somefile.txt");
```

where the `GetMD5HashFromFile` function could look like this:

```
public static string GetMD5HashFromFile(string filename)
{
    using (var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var buffer = md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(buffer[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: and how would you do all this all self contained (i.e no read from other text files) O.o?

Comment: like wouldnt there be a way for the application to generate the md5 hash and display it in a label without it having to read it from a text file?

Comment: @NightsEVil There is the other way, you can use function from System.Magic, MD5MagicReader.GetMD5ForFileYouKnowWhichWithoutReading()

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  When you calculate the MD5 Hash of a file you just need to take the result and place it in as the text of Label control.  No problem there.

Comment: and how would you do all this all self contained (i.e no read from other text files) O.o?